# Swift IOS using config properties for Google GMSPlacePicker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I know this is a high level question how to read documentation regarding this iOS SDK.

How would I use these properties to config the GMSPlacesClient to restrict a user from scrolling away from their current location etc?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_u_i_settings

Any guidance on how to read and leverage this would be great!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These settings are super useful, and very easy to implement. If you want to turn off scrolling, for example, you could set up your code like this:

```
let yourGMV = GMSMapView() //If you already have your own GMSView, disregard this line!
yourGMV.settings.scrollGestures = false
```

You can do with all the settings described in the documentation you posted just by using the `.settings` method.

Comment: Ah ok that makes perfect sense now. I wasn't quite sure how to interpret the documentation into Swift code.

Comment: Do you know if these can be used with GMSPlacesClient?

Comment: The specific page of documentation you linked to is not applicable to GMSPlacesClient i.e. a GMSPlaceClient object won't have any .settings stuff. However, google's got a list of things you CAN do with it! https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_places_client